# Angular JS and ASP Server Side Control Validation

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, validation, server-side, validationsummary

I am using angular JS for asp.net server side controls

```
<div class="gridpage mb40" name="myForm" ng-model="myForm" ng-form
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="">Name of the Supplier:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSupName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ng-model="txtSupName" name="txtName" required></asp:TextBox>
        <p ng-show="myForm.txtName.$invalid && !myForm.txtName.$pristine" class="help-block">Your Name is Required.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

problem is at run time when i deploy my code , name property changes for server side control so i am not able to render paragraph of error messages
is there any other way through which i can access control instead of myform.txtName.$invalid??

tried with `clientIDmode= Static` , it keeps id static but name still changes,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/u4s4vzcc/).

Create a directive `alias`, which stores a reference to `ngModelController`, which is independent of the `name` of input (asp:TextBox).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $log) {

  })
  .directive('alias', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: "ngModel",
      scope: {
        alias: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
        scope.alias = ngModel;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
      <input name="txtName" ng-model="txtName" required alias="aliasName" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/">
      <div ng-if="myForm.txtName.$error.required">Name is reauired by name</div>
      <div ng-if="aliasName.$error.required">Name is reauired by alias</div>
      <div ng-if="myForm.txtName.$error.pattern">Invalid pattern by name</div>
      <div ng-if="aliasName.$error.pattern">Invalid pattern by alias</div>
      <br>
      <pre>myForm.txtName.$error = {{myForm.txtName.$error|json}}</pre>
      <pre>aliasName.$error = {{aliasName.$error|json}}</pre>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```